# Probability: 2 random numbers such that $x > 2y$

Tags: probability

This is probably an easy one, but I'm new to probability and really don't know how to solve this question.

Select two numbers randomly from interval $[0, 1]$ call them $x$ and $y$, what is the 
probability that $x$, (the first number) is greater that $2y$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Draw the part $T$ of the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ defined by the inequation $x\gt2y$. (Sub-hint: $T$ is a triangle.) Measure the area of $T$. Conclude.

Comment: Just for my understanding, what do you mean with _T_? What's the definition?

Comment: @Hans see my picture. $x>2y$ is the portion of the rectangle with $(x,y)$ coordinates below the line $y=\frac{1}{2}x$

Comment: *What's the definition?* Please read: `the part T of the square [0,1]×[0,1] defined by the inequation x>2y`.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour Thanks for the picture.

Comment: @Did No problemo

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is the shaded part of this picture: 
[image]

$x>2y$ is the portion of the rectangle with $(x,y)$ coordinates below the line $y=\frac{1}{2}x$

Answer (score 0):

If $y = t$, then valid $x$ points are located above the ${x}\gt{2t}$ (see yellow area in image).  Probability is the contents of the yellow triangle(${{{{1}\over{2}}\cdot{1}}\over{2}}$) divided by the contents of the entire square (${1}\cdot{1}$).
So the value being queried:  $$p(x > 2y) = {{1}\over{4}}$$

[image]

Comment: Thx, this really helps me to understand the situation :)